# If ER = EPR conjecture is true would it allow faster than light (FTL) communication?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light

If entanglement is really carried through by wormholes can't we for instance use that wormhole to send information through it? If we understand that maybe we can scale up the wormhole to allow people to transverse through it?

Comment: You can't send information through a wormhole faster than it could travel through the space outside the wormhole. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.04726 and references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, a wormhole between distant points in spacetime means that there are paths (going through the wormhole) whose lengths can be much smaller than those of the 'regular' paths going outside the wormhole. (Think of the usual picture of a bent piece of paper with a tunnel connecting the two sides).

As such, objects moving through the wormhole do not strictly speaking travel faster than light, they just reach their destination faster by taking shorter paths through spacetime.

(This is regardless of whether the ER=EPR conjecture is true or not)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is definitely negative: as various analises proved, **it is not possible to transmit suprluminal information through entaglement**, no matter if it can be represented as a wormhole (and I am very very sceptical on this latter conjecture).

On the other hand, the side ER in the fantastic identity ER=EPR denotes the Einstein-Rosen wormhole which, as is well known, **it cannot be crossed by causal curves**.

As macroscopic physical  information is supposed to be transported along causal curves, we conclude that **the very identity cannot permit superluminal transmission of information**: though the opposite sides of the ER whormole are spatially seprated but joined by a whormhole, no physical communication can exist between the two sides.